# How to copy custom ObservableCollection elements to another custom ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf, list, observablecollection

I created a MTObservableCollection class that derives from ObservableCollection for multithreading. This is how the function looks like:

```
public class MTObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T: LogClassa
    {
        public MTObservableCollection() { }

        public override event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
        protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged = this.CollectionChanged;
            if (CollectionChanged != null)
                foreach (NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler nh in CollectionChanged.GetInvocationList())
                {
                    DispatcherObject dispObj = nh.Target as DispatcherObject;
                    if (dispObj != null)
                    {
                        Dispatcher dispatcher = dispObj.Dispatcher;
                        if (dispatcher != null && !dispatcher.CheckAccess())
                        {
                            dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                                (Action)(() => nh.Invoke(this,
                                    new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset))),
                                DispatcherPriority.DataBind);
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    nh.Invoke(this, e);
                }
        }
    }
```

And here is my LogClass

```
public class LogClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string timestamp;
    private string title;
    private string message;
    private MTObservableCollection<LogClass> childRowLog = new MTObservableCollection<LogClass>();

    public string TimeStamp 
    {
         get { return timestamp; }
         set 
         {
              if( timestamp != value )
              {
                   timestamp = value;
                   OnPropertyChanged("TimeStamp");
              }
         }
    }

    public string Title
    {
         get { return title; }
         set 
         {
              if( title!= value )
              {
                   title= value;
                   OnPropertyChanged("Title");
              }
         }
    }

    public string Message
    {
         get { return message; }
         set 
         {
              if( message!= value )
              {
                   message= value;
                   OnPropertyChanged("Message");
              }
         }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

So if I have two MTObservableCollection collections and I add elements to one of them such as:

```
public static MTObservableCollection<LogClass> parentLogCollection = new MTObservableCollection<LogClass>();
public MTObservableCollection<LogClass> childLogCollection = new MTObservableCollection<LogClass>();

childLogClass.Add( new LogClass { TimeStamp = "time", Title = "title", Message = "message" } );
```

Now if I want to add childLogCollection to parentLogCollection, I would do this:

```
parentLogCollection = new MTObservableCollection<LogClass>(childLogCollection);
```

I would think I need to create an implementation within the MBObservationCollection class which should be

```
public MTObservableCollection(MTObservableCollection<T> collection)
{

}
```

I just don't know what to input into it, how would I perform it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the parent of your `MTObservableCollection` like this:

```
public MTObservableCollection(MTObservableCollection<T> collection) : base(collection)
{

}
```